# I feed my cat by myself / myself / on my own

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

How is it natural to say:

> I feed my cat **by myself**.
>
> I feed my cat **myself**.
>
> I feed my cat **on my own**.

I'm afraid, only the second version is in the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feed%20it%20by%20myself%2Cfeed%20it%20myself%2C%20feed%20it%20on%20my%20own&year_start=1800&year_end=2018&case_insensitive=on&corpus=15&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeed%20it%20myself%3B%2Cc0). Why? Maybe, you just say "Only I feed my cat."?

Comment: I do my homework by myself. I do my homework myself. I do my homework on my own. Not everything is "already written".

Comment: "I feed my cat by myself" sounds as though you are suggesting that it is unusual not to need help with doing so! Do you mean "I am the only person who feeds my cat"?

Comment: @Kate Bunting: Yes, I meant "I am the only person who feeds my cat". What version is idiomatic?

Comment: As Randomhead suggests, _I feed my cat myself_ is the best of your three options. _I am the only person who feeds my cat_ expresses the meaning clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings are not all the same:

> I feed my cat **by myself**.

I feed my cat without assistance.

> I feed my cat **myself**.

I am the one who feeds my cat, no one else. (I do not have anyone else do it *for me*.)

> I feed my cat **on my own**.

I am alone when I feed my cat.

---

**By myself** and **on my own** have overlapping meanings; the distinction I made above is what I thought of first, but it wouldn't be incorrect to say the meanings are swapped, or that both phrases have both meanings. It depends on the context in which they're used.

Comment: Anyway, I upvied you. :)